# Not async Ajax ignoring functions after the call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following function:

```
    $("#transfer").click(function(){
        var token_rec = $("#token_rec").val();
        var user_rec = $("#user_rec").val();
        var subdomain_rec = $("#subdominio_rec").val();
        var req_rec = $("#req_rec").val();
        var acao_rec = $("#acao_rec").val();
        var section_rec = $("#section_rec").val();
        if(!token_rec || !user_rec || !subdomain_rec || !req_rec || !acao_rec || !section_rec){
            alert("Preencha todos os campos de recebimento.");
        } else {
            $("#transfer").hide();
            $("#loading").show();
            $("#accordion_rec").empty();
            var abody = "";
            var c = $(this).attr("count");
            for(var i=0; i<c; i++){
                if($("#check_ret"+i).is(":checked")){
                    var json_dec = decodeURI($("#check_ret"+i).val());
                    var json_es1 = json_dec.replace(/="/g, '=\\"');
                    var json_es2 = json_es1.replace(/">/g, '\\">');
                    var json_es3 = json_es2.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '');
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "php/curlWrap_rec.php",
                        data: {token: token_rec, user: user_rec, subdomain: subdomain_rec, req: req_rec, acao: acao_rec, json: json_es3},
                        success: function(data){
                            var data_parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                            abody+= '<div style="border:solid 1px #ccc">';
                            abody+= '<p style="cursor:pointer" onclick="accordion(\'#rec_slide'+i+'\')"><strong>'+data_parsed.article.title+'</strong></p>';
                            abody+= '<div id="rec_slide'+i+'" style="display:none">'+data_parsed.article.body+'</div>';
                            abody+= '</div>';
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            $("#loading").hide();
            $("#transfer").show();
            $("#accordion_rec").append(abody);
        }
    });
```

It's working fine, however it seems to be ignoring the part of the code where I hide the $("#transfer") and show the $("#loading") before the call.

Why this is happening and how can I correct this?

Comment: `async: false` locks up the browser until it's complete.  Why are you using that?  I wonder if that's the reason your code is being "ignored".  JavaScript is single-threaded and your AJAX calls will take over that thread and block anything else from running.

Comment: I'm using async: false, because else he ignores my loop and all the results comes out with the same index.

Comment: Using `async: false` is *not* the correct solution to that problem.  That's happening because the each AJAX callback is using the same `i` variable.  You need to create a closure for each one, so each can use its own `i` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you do not use `async: false`.  It locks up the browser and I think is what's causing your issue.  Your code is not being "ignored", but rather *blocked* until the AJAX call(s) complete.

You should really let AJAX calls remain asynchronous and manage your callback(s) accordingly.

In this case, you need to create a closure for *each* AJAX call, because they are currently sharing the same `i` variable.

```
for(var i=0; i<c; i++){
    if($("#check_ret"+i).is(":checked")){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/curlWrap_rec.php",
            dataType: 'json', // <- this will call JSON.parse for you
            data: {token: token_rec, user: user_rec, subdomain: subdomain_rec, req: req_rec, acao: acao_rec, json: json_es3},
            success: (function(i){
                // What's happening here is that a *new* function is generated
                // and returned each iteration of the `for` loop.
                // This lets each callback have its own `i` value.
                return function(data){
                    // Since this is now asynchronous, we can't
                    // append to the "global" `abody`, each callback
                    // needs its own.
                    var abody = '<div style="border:solid 1px #ccc">' +
                        '<p style="cursor:pointer" onclick="accordion(\'#rec_slide'+i+'\')"><strong>'+data.article.title+'</strong></p>'+
                        '<div id="rec_slide'+i+'" style="display:none">'+data.article.body+'</div>'+
                        '</div>';
                    $("#accordion_rec").append(abody);
                };
            }(i))
        });
    }
}
```

Another thing you can do here is use deferreds/promises to wait until *all* the AJAX calls are done before appending to the element.

```
// We'll store the promises returned by $.ajax here,
// so we can add the callback(s) later
var ajax_calls = [];

$("#transfer").hide();
$("#loading").show();
$("#accordion_rec").empty();

for(var i=0; i<c; i++){
    if($("#check_ret"+i).is(":checked")){
        // This returns a promise which we are saving for later
        ajax_calls.push($.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/curlWrap_rec.php",
            data: {token: token_rec, user: user_rec, subdomain: subdomain_rec, req: req_rec, acao: acao_rec, json: json_es3}
        }));
    }
}

// Wait for *all* the promises to complete
$.when.apply($, ajax_calls).done(function(){
    var abody = "";

    // This function is passed one parameter for each AJAX call,
    // in the order they were added to the `ajax_calls` array.
    // So we can just loop over `arguments` and get the correct data
    // and `i` value.
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        abody+= '<div style="border:solid 1px #ccc">';
        abody+= '<p style="cursor:pointer" onclick="accordion(\'#rec_slide'+i+'\')"><strong>'+arguments[i][0].article.title+'</strong></p>';
        abody+= '<div id="rec_slide'+i+'" style="display:none">'+arguments[i][0].article.body+'</div>';
        abody+= '</div>';
    }

    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#transfer").show();
    $("#accordion_rec").append(abody);
});
```

Comment: I was about to write an answer similar to yours using $.when, this is the best solution

Comment: @zerohero: Great minds think alike, eh? ;-)  Yeah, when you are doing AJAX calls in a loop, then `$.when` is probably a good choice :)

Comment: Mr. Rocket, both of your solutions are behaving the same way as mine. MY loading gif is not showing on click, but the function is working.

Comment: @GabrielBertolim: What is `$("#loading")`?  What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Its a img tag: <img id="loading" src="assets/loading_spinner.gif" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%; display:none;" />

Comment: @GabrielBertolim: Does it work if you enter `$("#loading").show();` into the JavaScript console?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yes. I have other functions that uses this loading gif and it's working fine on them.

Answer (score -1):

Check the page contain only one transfer element and loading element. If there are more than one element with same ID.